# Bootstrap data-offset-top = "variable"?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

At the moment I am using an sticky menu that start at a fix distance of 560px of the top of the monitor as you see in the code, but of course it dos not work always well.

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="560" role="navigation">
```

After scrolling the menu will be fixed at the top of the screen, as usual.

My question:

**I would like to fix the navbar at 75% of the top of the monitor, regardless the monitor size. How could I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use JavaScript/jQuery and return a value that calculates 75% of the viewport height..

```
$('#site-navigation').affix({
      offset: {
        top: $(window).height() * .75
      }
});
```

[Here is an example](http://www.codeply.com/go/beLmje5j5W). The "header" is 75% of viewport height, and the nav attaches when the scroll hits the bottom of the "header".

http://www.codeply.com/go/beLmje5j5W